Filter by unique counts within groups
I'm trying to filter by the count of unique items within groups.
For example, suppose I have the following data set:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'data': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2],
    'group': [1,1,1,2,2,1,1],
    'id': [1,2,3,4,5,1,2],
    'x': [1,1,2,1,2,1,1]
})

Where (data, group) is a compound key for groups of items that each have an 'id' and an 'x' value. I'd like to filter the data set to only keep groups that have at least two different 'x' values, 1 and 2.
I tried the following but get an error message:
df.filter(pl.col('x').unique_counts().over(['data', 'group']) >= 2)

ComputeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-e6f9db2d2a13> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.filter(pl.col('x').unique_counts().over(['data', 'group']) >= 2)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py in collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, slice_pushdown, comm_subplan_elim, comm_subexpr_elim, no_optimization, streaming, _eager)
   1704             _eager,
   1705         )
-> 1706         return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
   1707 
   1708     @overload

ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong, or how to achieve this goal?

.n_unique() seems to work! If you add that as a top-level reply I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you!

.n_unique() will give you the number of unique values.
df.filter(pl.col('x').n_unique().over('data', 'group') >= 2)

shape: (5, 4)
┌──────┬───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ data ┆ group ┆ id  ┆ x   │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1    ┆ 1     ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ 1    ┆ 1     ┆ 3   ┆ 2   │
│ 1    ┆ 2     ┆ 4   ┆ 1   │
│ 1    ┆ 2     ┆ 5   ┆ 2   │
└──────┴───────┴─────┴─────┘

The problem with .unique_counts() is that it returns multiple values.
In a "groupby context" (i.e. using .agg() or .over()) it will produce a list.
>>> df.group_by("group", "data").agg(count = pl.col("x").unique_counts())
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ group ┆ data ┆ count     │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1    ┆ [2, 1]    │
│ 2     ┆ 1    ┆ [1, 1]    │
│ 1     ┆ 2    ┆ [2]       │
└───────┴──────┴───────────┘

Whereas you need a single value for the .filter() logic to make sense.
>>> df.group_by("group", "data").agg(count = pl.col("x").n_unique())
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ data ┆ count │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 2    ┆ 1     │
│ 2     ┆ 1    ┆ 2     │
│ 1     ┆ 1    ┆ 2     │
└───────┴──────┴───────┘

